# What is a good probability model of the distribution of frequencies as represented by western sheet music?

Tags: musical-data-analysis

I'm attempting to answer a general question about a method of musical comparision which is generalizable beyond western music but uses western music scales as a nearly sufficient subspace for dimensional reduction. What is a good probability model of the distribution of frequencies as represented by western sheet music for SATB and instruments?

Comment: Are you aware of any papers that fit probability models to music frequencies? Music research isn't my area.

Comment: @Glen_b It wouldn't be all that difficult to calculate like P(x_hz|tenor or bar or bass)

Comment: "Frequency" as a physical measurement actually has little intrinsic meaning in western music, most of which is based on the *relative* frequencies within a particular paradigm of composition, performance, and listening. Coupled with the impossibly vague referent of "western sheet music," this would seem to make the question unanswerable. Perhaps you would like to make some clarifying edits to remove these ambiguities?

Comment: www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html so they are set sources of tuning

Comment: No mod purge at all: the owner of two comments in this thread deleted them himself. As far as your reference goes, that explicitly concerns the *physics* of music. Some such method to standardize notes is needed to help different instruments play in tune together (and these methods have evolved and varied over the years), but it neither characterizes western music nor is essential for its performance, understanding, or analysis. (In fact, most likely only music instrument makers and piano tuners know or really care about any of that information.)

Comment: @whuber my uh producer knew about the tonal frequencies he says he uses them to some limited degree he has to avoid doing accidental ANC but its mostly from memorization from his school i think

Comment: *Remark:* Uninformative comments were removed from this thread.